# Subscript of a struct doesn't set values when created as an implicitly unwrapped optional

Tags: swift, class, struct, swift2, option-type

Why can't I change the the "numbers" array using subscripts when "Foo" is an implicitly unwrapped optional?

```
struct Foo {
    var numbers = [0,0,0]
    subscript(index: Int) -> Int {
        get { return self.numbers[index] }
        set { self.numbers[index] = newValue }
    }
}


var fooA:Foo!
fooA = Foo()

fooA[1] = 1              // does not change numbers array
fooA[1]                  // returns 0

fooA.numbers[1] = 1      // this works
fooA[1]                  // returns 1

var fooB:Foo!
fooB = Foo()

fooB![1] = 1              // this works
fooB![1]                  // returns 1
```

For some reason it works when I make "Foo" a class (called "Goo" below)

```
class Goo {
    var numbers = [0,0,0]
    subscript(index: Int) -> Int {
        get { return self.numbers[index] }
        set { self.numbers[index] = newValue }
    }
}

var goo:Goo!
goo = Goo()

goo[1] = 1              // this works
goo[1]                  // returns 1
```

Comment: When you unwrap the variable explicitly it works : ` fooA![1] = 1` . But before declaring any implicit unwrapped optional variable consider to use a non optional initialized lazily : `var fooA : Foo = { return Foo() }()`

Comment: that is true. But why doesn't it work without explicitly unwrapping the variable?

Comment: I don't know, that's why I wrote a comment rather than an answer ;-)

Comment: @vadian that is the trouble.  var i: Int!!! = 10; print(i) // 10 ????????? it looks really, really strange! but ... it works (for unknown reason)

Comment: Does replacing `set` in the subscript with `mutating set` make any difference?

Comment: @fluidsonic it does not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like a bug (or i miss something important), check this

```
struct Foo {
    var numbers = [0,0,0]
    subscript(index: Int) -> Int {
        get {
            return self.numbers[index]
        }
        set {
            numbers[index] = newValue
        }
    }
}


var fooA:Foo! = Foo()
// here is the difference
fooA?[1] = 1
fooA[1]                  //  1
fooA.numbers[1] = 1
fooA[1]                  //  1
```

more 'complex' experiment

```
struct Foo {
    var numbers = [0,0,0]
    subscript(index: Int) -> Int {
        get {
            return numbers[index]
        }
        set {
            print(numbers[index],newValue)
            numbers[index] = newValue
            print(numbers[index])
        }
    }
}


var fooA:Foo! = Foo()

fooA[1] = 1
fooA[1]                  // 0
// but prints
// 0 1
// 1
```

for more 'fun'

```
var fooA:Foo! = Foo()
if var foo = fooA {
    foo[1] = 1
    print(foo)
}
```

prints

```
"Foo(numbers: [0, 1, 0])\n"
```

Comment: assuming you're right, where and how would I report swift bugs?

Comment: if you have developers account, do it on apple radar

Comment: at least fooA?[1] should be recognized as invalid expression